# Debian / Linux xrdp

Tags: linux, debian, rdp

I installed xrdp on Debian Wheezy (+vnc4server as a dependency) and I have 3 questions:

1) Is there any way to recconet user to previous xrdp sessman-Xvnc session? If user change his resolution or color depth, he just get new session and cant access applications running before.

2) How can I limit connections to 1 session per user?

3) I readed that sessman-X11rdp has a feature i need, but it ceeps crashing with error "another Xserver is alreadry active on display 11".